# onClick only works if I press it longer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, onclick

I'm trying to trigger some functions when I'm clicking on a input field. The thing is it only works if I click for like half a second. For example if I click like I would click into a directory in Windows it's not working great. But if I hold the click longer it's working fine. Any suggestions?

Here is my code.

html:

```js
function closeOrderUnit(){
    $('.massclose').click(function(e){
        $(this).parents('td').children('.massbox, .mass_arrow').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
function changeUnit(){  
    $('.massbox input').click(function(){
        var label = $(this).parents('.massbox').parents("td").children("div").children('label');
        var input = $(this).parents('.massbox').parents("td").children("input.hiddenInput");
        var str = $(this).val();
        //Turning first letter into uppercase
        str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
            if(str.length > 2){
                return letter.toUpperCase();
            }else {
                return letter.toLowerCase();
            }
        });
        if(str == "m2"){
            str = str.replace("2", "\u00B2");
        }
        label.html(str);
        input.val($(this).val());
    });
}
function checkUnit(){
    $('.unitinput').each(function(){
        var temp =  $('.massbox').parents("td").children("div").children('label').html();
        if(temp == "m²"){
            temp = "M2";
        }else if(temp == "Rolle"){
            temp = "ROLLE";
        }
        if ($(this).val() == temp)
        {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });

}
function inputValueChanged(){
    $('.js-ordersize-input').change(function(){
    var tmp = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", tmp);
    });

}
function magicMassBox(){
    inputValueChanged();
    closeOrderUnit();
    checkUnit();
    changeUnit();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ordersize').each(function(){
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "0")
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
            $('.massbox, .mass_arrow').remove();
            $(this).parent().append(
                '<div class="massbox"></div>',
                '<div class="mass_arrow"><img alt="arrow" src="/resources/css/screen/images/arrow_box_einheiten.png"></div>'
            );
            var code = $(this).parents('.odd').children('.firstcol').children('input').val();
            if(code == null || code == "")
            {
                code = $(this).parents('.highlighted').children('.firstcol').children('input').val();
            }
            $('.massbox').load('/c/product/units?code='+code, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){});
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "")
            {
                $(this).val("0");
            }
        });
    });
    $('.ordersize').on('click', function(){
        magicMassBox();
    });
    $(".js-muster-disable").change(handleMusterCheck);
});
```

```html
<input class="ordersize js-ordersize-input" name="amount_195.050" id="amount_195.050" tabindex="" value="0" type="text">
    <input name="unit_195.050" value="M2" class="hiddenInput" type="hidden">
 <div class="pt5px fleft w25px"><label id="label_195.050">m²</label></div><br>
  <div style="display: none;">
   <div>
    <p>M2</p>
    <p>m²</p>
    <p>m²</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="massbox"> 
     <p class="masseinheit">Bestelleinheit:</p>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <input class="unitinput" name="unit" value="M2" checked="checked" type="radio">
   m²
   <input class="unitinput" name="unit" value="ROLLE" type="radio">
   Rl.
 </div>
```

JSP (I have to make a check if something is enabled else this would be in the .js as well)

```
<c:if test="${product.enableUnitSelection}">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ordersize').each(function(){
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "0")
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
            $('.massbox, .mass_arrow').remove();
            $(this).parent().append(
                '<div class="massbox"></div>',
                '<div class="mass_arrow"><img alt="arrow" src="/resources/css/screen/images/arrow_box_einheiten.png"></div>'
            );
            var code = $(this).parents('.odd').children('.firstcol').children('input').val();
            if(code == null || code == "")
            {
                code = $(this).parents('.highlighted').children('.firstcol').children('input').val();
            }
            $('.massbox').load('/c/product/units?code='+code, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){});
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "")
            {
                $(this).val("0");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</c:if>
<script src="/resources/js/webtable.js"></script>
```

And my .js Code

```
function closeOrderUnit(){
    $('.massclose').click(function(e){
        $(this).parents('td').children('.massbox, .mass_arrow').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
function changeUnit(){  
    $('.massbox input').click(function(){
        var label = $(this).parents('.massbox').parents("td").children("div").children('label');
        var input = $(this).parents('.massbox').parents("td").children("input.hiddenInput");
        var str = $(this).val();
        //Turning first letter into uppercase
        str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
            if(str.length > 2){
                return letter.toUpperCase();
            }else {
                return letter.toLowerCase();
            }
        });
        if(str == "m2"){
            str = str.replace("2", "\u00B2");
        }
        label.html(str);
        input.val($(this).val());
    });
}
function checkUnit(){
    $('.unitinput').each(function(){
        var temp =  $('.massbox').parents("td").children("div").children('label').html();
        if(temp == "m²"){
            temp = "M2";
        }else if(temp == "Rolle"){
            temp = "ROLLE";
        }
        if ($(this).val() == temp)
        {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });

}
function inputValueChanged(){
    $('.js-ordersize-input').change(function(){
    var tmp = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", tmp);
    });

}
function magicMassBox(){
    inputValueChanged();
    closeOrderUnit();
    checkUnit();
    changeUnit();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ordersize').on('click', function(){
        magicMassBox();
    });
    $(".js-muster-disable").change(handleMusterCheck);
});
```

Comment: Add some html and try to reproduce the problem in snippet "<>"  if you can, it will help us help you

Comment: The code snippet is way too long lmao.